# i can't use the Repository anymore

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I developed an application using spring boot and it used to work just fine I stopped working on it for a while but today when I tried to run it  one of my repositories stopped working and is giving me an error I don't know why 
this is the error :

```
2019-06-24 16:00:29.056 ERROR 11140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'produitController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'produitReposotry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'produitReposotry': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:626) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:385) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:868) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:404) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1275) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1263) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at com.example.databasedemo.DatabasedemoApplication.main(DatabasedemoApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'produitReposotry': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1783) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:623) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:563) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:556) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1052) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:558) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:321) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1842) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1779) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 78 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

here is my classes :

```
package com.example.databasedemo.produit;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;

public interface produitReposotry extends JpaRepository<produit,Integer> {


    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT p.nomprod FROM produit p ")
    List<String> findNonReferencedNames();

    List<produit> findByOrderByDateAsc();
   // List<produit> findDistinctByNomprod(List<String> names);
    List<produit> findAllByNomprodOrderByDateAsc(String Nom_prod);


}
```

and :

```
package com.example.databasedemo;


import com.example.databasedemo.produit.produit;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/allproduits")
public class produitController {

    @Autowired
    com.example.databasedemo.produit.produitReposotry produitReposotry;

    /*********************get all personnel**********************/
    @GetMapping("/produits")
    public List<produit> getAllproduits() {

        List<produit> produits = new ArrayList<>();

            produitReposotry.findByOrderByDateAsc().forEach(produits::add);
        produits.forEach(produit -> System.out.println(produit.getDate()));
        return produits;
    }
    @GetMapping("/bynomprod/{nomprod}")
    public List<produit> getbynomprod(@PathVariable(value = "nomprod") String np) {

        List<produit> produits = new ArrayList<>();

            produitReposotry.findAllByNomprodOrderByDateAsc(np).forEach(produits::add);

        return produits;
    }
    @GetMapping("/distacntproduits")
    public List<String> getdis() {

        List<String> produits = new ArrayList<>();

        produitReposotry.findNonReferencedNames().forEach(produits::add);

        return produits;
    }
    /*****************************get one personnel***************************/
    @GetMapping("/produitsbyid/{id}")
    public produit getproduitbyId(@PathVariable(value = "id") int ID) {
        produit produit =produitReposotry.findById(ID).get();
     /*   List<personnel> personnelbyid = new ArrayList<>();
        personnelbyid.add(personnel);*/
        return produit;
    }
    /*********************add personnel**********************************/
    @PostMapping("/addprod")
    public  List<produit> Add(@RequestBody produit produit) {
        produitReposotry.save(produit);
        return produitReposotry.findAll();
    }
    /******************delete personnel****************************/

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteprduit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> delete(@PathVariable(value = "id") int ID)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        produit produit = produitReposotry.findById(ID)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("personnel not found for this id :: " + ID));
        if(produit!=null)
        {  produitReposotry.delete(produit);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("produit has been deleted!", HttpStatus.OK);}
        else{return new ResponseEntity<>("produit was not found!", HttpStatus.OK);}

    }
    /********************edit personnel*************************************/
    @PostMapping("/updateprod")
    public  List<produit> updateprod(@Valid @RequestBody produit produit) {
        produitReposotry.save(produit);
        return produitReposotry.findAll();
    }
}
```

I don't know what happened so it stops working suddenly  if anyone knows why I am getting this error please tell me i really need it 
even when i tried to delete this repository the other ones stopped working

**edit :**
now the whole app is not working i get this error :

```
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe" -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Desktop\Java-RxTx-in-Windows-10-USB-COM-ports-master\Win10RxTx -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=58953:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\IdeaProjects\databasedemo\target\classes;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.4\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.24\snakeyaml-1.24.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.11.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.11.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.8\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.8\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.19\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.19\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.19.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.19\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.1\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.16.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.0.M2\spring-web-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.2.0.M2\spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.0.M2\spring-expression-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc\6.4.0.jre8\mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.12\byte-buddy-1.9.12.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.0.M2\spring-core-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.0.M2\spring-jcl-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.3.1\HikariCP-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.0.M2\spring-jdbc-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.1\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.2\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.2\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.2.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Desktop\Java-RxTx-in-Windows-10-USB-COM-ports-master\Win10RxTx\lib\RXTXcomm.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.0\classmate-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.2\txw2-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.8\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.1\stax-ex-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.16\FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.2.0.M4\spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.2.0.M4\spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.2.0.M2\spring-orm-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.0.M2\spring-tx-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.2.0.M2\spring-aspects-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.7\velocity-1.7.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-security-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.0.M2\spring-aop-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.2.0.M2\spring-security-web-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.2.0.M2\spring-security-config-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.2.0.M2\spring-security-core-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.0.M2\spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.0.M2\spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fazecast\jSerialComm\2.5.1\jSerialComm-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.6.2\javax.mail-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mail\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-mail-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\5.2.0.M2\spring-context-support-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\rxtx\rxtx\2.1.7\rxtx-2.1.7.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\bidib\com\neuronrobotics\nrjavaserial\3.12.0\nrjavaserial-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\3.3\commons-net-3.3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.9\commons-lang3-3.9.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-websocket\4.1.6.RELEASE\spring-websocket-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-function-adapter-sample\1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-function-adapter-sample-1.0.0.BUILD-20170627.122039-9.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws\1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws-1.0.0.BUILD-20180618.091103-352.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-function-context\1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-function-context-1.0.0.BUILD-20180618.090751-398.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-function-core\1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-function-core-1.0.0.BUILD-20180618.090651-400.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\reactor-core\3.3.0.M1\reactor-core-3.3.0.M1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.2\reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.2.0.M2\spring-messaging-5.2.0.M2.jar com.example.databasedemo.DatabasedemoApplication
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/spi/LifeCycle
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at
```

Comment: If this is a maven/gradle project, try to refresh the dependencies because this errors are all related with missing dependencies like this: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
 <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId>
 <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>   it is not finding.

Comment: thank you i added this and it workes <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: That is great @ela .. i added the answer then so people know how you fixed it.

Comment: check your missing dependencies, it looks like some issues with your maven dependencies tree use this command - mvn dependency:tree

Comment: @Brother the problem is fixed and the app is running fine but i got this  HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection ConnectionID:2 ClientConnectionId: what is it

Comment: Hi @ElaHidri, the Hikari just check a pool of connections to see if they are open/closed. Maybe increasing timeouts in the DB like MySQL or the time for the connection can help. But it is supposed to be a warning only right?

Comment: yeah it is just a warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Ela Hidri 
The problem was a missing dependency:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId> 
    <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId> 
    <version>3.5.2</version> 
</dependency>
```